# Discovering mistakes in thesis after submission and printing

Tags: thesis, errors-erratum

So here is my issue - I submitted my thesis 2 years ago and it was accepted and i was granted the M.S. degree (I am in the US, BTW).
Now, when I opened it to read some portions, I found some missing references to data tables, and otherwise some typos.
I am starting to freak out about this, because of the consequences. My question is this - can the university somehow "re-evaluate" my thesis and find it unacceptable? I am not sure about how it works in academia, any help would be appreciated.
Edit: My question is bit different than the others, as it is asking whether the university has the power to "re-evaluate" my thesis based on typos and omissions.

Comment: For all practical purposes every thesis written in human history has typos in it.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: Titles are usually rescinded for actual deliberate misconduct (think "lying", not "being wrong"). Almost all theses have errors in them. If you want the record to be set right, you can post a corrected version of your thesis on your website (or on the arXiv if the subject is one of the arXiv subjects).

Answer (score 2):

The examination regulations specify what needs to happen so that a "re-evaluation" of an accepted thesis becomes due. Generally, such re-evaluations only take place in case of severe academic misconduct, like plagiarism or faking data. In the case of minor presentation issues, there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: The recent rescinding of PhD titles in Germany were cases of plagiarism, "delegating research work", or outright faking of data. Honest mistakes, and especially if they are minor, such as typos or omissions, should not be expected to lead to the revoking of a PhD, much less an MSc title.